# How to subset dataframe using multiple columns from another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames. One is my main database, the other is a subset of the database

```
print(database)
col1 col2 x y
###  ###  1 1
###  ###  2 3
###  ###  4 5

print(selection)
x y
1 1
2 3
```

I need to get all rows from "database" that have x and y coordinates reflected in the selection. I know I can use the "subset()" operator to extract rows from database using a selection criteria, for example

```
subset(database, database$x == 1 & database$y == 1)
```

would return the first row in my database. But how can I apply this selection operator to search for multiple selection criteria? One approach I could try would be to use a nested for loop and the subset operator as described above, but it seems apparent to me that using for loops in R is frowned upon, so there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a join in dplyr:

```
matches <- database %>%
    inner_join(selection, by=c("x","y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example for selection in the same dataframe should have been:

subset(database, x == 1 & y == 1)

But to answer your question, you could use `merge`:

```
merge(database, selection, by=c("x","y") )
```

It could also be doen when the columns in the "selection" dataframe had names that were different than those of the target dataframe. See `?merge` for further examples.

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr, this can achieved by:
`res <- dplyr::inner_join(database, selection, by = c("x" = "x", "y" = "y"))`

For large tables in R dplyr's function inner_join() is much faster than merge().

Other advantages are :

- rows are kept in existing order
- much faster
- tells you what keys you’re merging by (if you don’t supply)
- also work with database tables.
  (from Hadley Wickham, dplyr's creator)